# FQL query returns no result

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a problem with my FQL query. I read all the related topic but I can't find my error.
My Facebook App has this permissions: email, user_birthday, user_likes, read_stream.
Inside a function I want to get if a user likes my page, but my query returns no result! The same query has been tested in Graph API explorer and I get a result. This is the function:

```
  function getUserInfo(accessToken) {

        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            var user_id = response.id;
            var page_id = "40796308305";   //page id for like
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + page_id + "and uid=" + user_id;   // +"&access_token=" + accessToken.toString();
            var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

            alert(fql_query);
```

// First Way

```
            FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: fql_query,
                access_token: accessToken
            }, function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
                if (resp.length) {
                    alert('A fan!');
                    $("#container_like").show();
                    $("#container_notlike").hide();

                    document.getElementById('displayname').innerHTML = response.name;
                    document.getElementById('FBId').innerHTML = response.id;
                } else {
                    alert('Not a fan!');
                    $("#container_notlike").show();
                    $("#container_like").hide();
                }
            }
            );
```

// Second Way

```
            the_query.wait(function (rows) {
                if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                    alert('A fan!');
                    $("#container_like").show();
                    $("#container_notlike").hide();
                    document.getElementById('displayname').innerHTML = response.name;
                    document.getElementById('FBId').innerHTML = response.id;
                } else {
                    alert('NOT a fan!');
                    $("#container_notlike").show();
                    $("#container_like").hide();
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

The accessToken is used in the Second Way inside the fql_query (commented now). I take it from code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {                    
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                getUserInfo(accessToken);
```

... etc. So I see all my alerts but query returns no data. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is be the issue, but I spent a lot of time only to figure out that I was running my javascript at localhost, but the url authorized with facebook was something else, and so I was getting unexpected failures. Something to quickly verify and eliminate the possibility.

Comment: You have a point. I published on server and FB.api is working but FB.Data.query(fql_query) is not. My problem now is that when user presses Like, page is reloaded but fql returns no like action. I must get out of application page and then visit again.